# How to trigger custom code before every method of a class is executed

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a pattern for Chrome Extensions where every time a method is called, based on whether the object is in "background script" or in "content script", either the method code is executed or a message is sent to background and the method is executed there. Manually written code would look like this:

```
class UnicornSpotter {

    constructor() {
         let that = this;
         listenToMessages((message) => {
             if(message === 'execute_unicorn_spotter') {
                 that.spot();
             }
         });
    }

    spot() {
        if(window.isBackgroundScript) {
             // Do the actual unicorn spotting here
        } else {
             sendMessageToBackgroundScript('execute_unicorn_spotter');
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine but I want to automate this message sending process so that I don't have to write code for each and every method separately. Is there a way in javascript that allows me to execute the message sending part automatically in the beginning of each method? Ideally, the methods would just contain the actual code and the message sending part is automatically triggered before the actual code.

Comment: This is the ideal job for [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: @wOxxOm Wao, I didn't know such an Object exists. It might be perfect to use here. Investigating now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you give more information maybe I can come up with something better.

```
class UnicornSpotter {
  constructor() {
    const actions = [{ name: 'execute_unicorn_spotter', func: 'spot' }];

    actions.forEach(({ name, func }) => {
      const current = this[func];
      this[func] = function () {
        if (!window.isBackgroundScript) {
          sendMessageToBackgroundScript(name);
        } else {
          current();
        }
      };
    });

    let that = this;
    listenToMessages((message) => that[actions.find(({ name }) => name === message).func]());
  }

  spot() {
    // Do the actual unicorn spotting here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the original functions to a new name (here it's postfixed by 'Impl') and then wrap all of them in new functions that call your 'autoCall' function beforehand.

You can check out the example below. But I'd advise extensive testing.

```
class Foo {
constructor() {
    this.wrapFunctions();
    console.log("-------------");
    this.function1("Jack",25);
    console.log("-------------");
    this.function2();
}
wrapFunctions() {
    var props = [];
    var defaultProps = [];
    var myObject = this;
    var obj = myObject;
    //Finding default properties for Object so we don't wrap them
    defaultProps = defaultProps.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf( new Object())));
    
    //Getting a list of all properties
    do {
        props = props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    //Finding functions and wrapping them
    props.sort().filter(function(e, i, arr) { 
       if (e!=arr[i+1] && typeof myObject[e] == 'function') {
           if(e != "autoCall" && defaultProps.indexOf(e) == -1){
                var realFunc = myObject[e];
                var newFuncName = e + "Impl";
                myObject[newFuncName] = realFunc;
                myObject[e] = function(...args){
                    this.autoCall();
                    this[newFuncName](...args);
                };
            }
        }
    });
}
autoCall(){
    console.log("autocall");
}
function1(name, age) {
    console.log("function1");
    console.log("name : " + name + " age : " + age);
}
function2() {
    console.log("This is function2");
}
}
var foo = new Foo();
```

### And the output will be

autocall

function1

name : Jack age : 25

---

autocall

This is function2